# single click or command setup for webserver on unix system

Tags: linux, installation, unix, apache-http-server, mysql

One of the product has requirement of on premise webserver. We are using LAMP stack. We have selected website for on premise use due to business constrains. We are to install this on multiple servers across multiple locations. We want to build setup process so that a non-technical person also can do the setup.

We are planning to use CentOS as the OS for the server. We want to create a setup which can setup Apache, MySQL and copy the files of our application on the system with minimum requirement of technical knowledge of the user. Which are the tools or methods should we be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question. However, there are three approaches you should consider:

1) The right way: set up a configuration and compliance management (CCM) solution such as Salt or Cfengine. It involves some overhead in the beginning but you will be able to configure and monitor your servers for compliance from your home base.

2) The quick and dirty way: a venerable BASH-Script (or any other scripting language you have available on your servers.) Just write a BASH-script to go through the motions and run it on all servers. You can do it yourself with something like pssh or, if you like, you can teach your non-technical person to run `./myScript.bash`.

3) The wrong way: build a metapackage including post-install scripts for yum and store it in a local repository. Configure the target servers to look at this repository and install from server with `yum install myPackage`.